# Why is there no network in my new Samsung Galaxy S2 when I insert my Prepaid Sim Card?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, connection-issues, sim-card

I bought a new Samsung Galaxy S2 and insert my Prepaid Singtel Sim card. When i turn it on, it doesn't have any network and states 'no service'

Comment: Is your SGS2 network unlocked? Did you buy it unlocked to any network?

Comment: I'm not  sure if its unlocked or not. What do you mean? Mind explaining in details?

Comment: See [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18324/android-sim-card-doesnt-allow-a-connection-to-this-network-error?rq=1)

Comment: I don't understand how its locked or unlocked..

Comment: Simple and brief explanation: Network carriers lock their handsets to the network, so it could be used only on that carrier. If it was unlocked, it could be used on any carrier.

Comment: Oh okay. So how do I unlock it back?

Comment: If you are on a contract with the carrier - you may have to fork out money to get it unlocked or possibly breach of their contract, or, go to some shady phone unlock shop or online, either way you will be charged.

Comment: oh so I need to get the help of a phone shop instead of myself doing it?

Comment: Yes, preferably they do that for you, rather than risking making a mess of the handset. :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

Your device is most likely sim-locked by your provider (even more likely if you bought it there for a discount, or got it free with your contract). So it will only work with SIM cards from that specific provider. If you want to use it with a different (pre-paid) card, you need to have your device unlocked first.

While it is generally possible to do that yourself, it will not only cost you time to figure out how, but you might also risk "making a mess" of it (as t0mm13b put it). So best is to go to some shop offering this service, and pay a little fee having them doing the job. Saves you at least some headaches.

See also:

- [“SIM card doesn't allow a connection to this network” ERROR](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/18324/16575)
- [Questions tagged "sim-unlocking"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the APN settings?   They are not always automatically generated.   Your carrier should provide instructions on how to add /check your APN settings.

Comment: Bearing in mind that the questioner probably doesn't know what APN settings are, would you like to explain this further?